# AppleTV and other Apple devices connecting by wifi but not by LAN

Tags: network, wifi, appletv, bonjour

I have an AppleTV in a local network that is connected by WiFi but it cannot find the iTunes library in my Mac that is connected via LAN to the router.

If I connect my Mac via WiFi, voilá, AppleTV is connected to my Mac without any problem.

If I connect both the AppleTV and my Mac via LAN, then they can connect without problem also.

The same issue occurs with an iPhone and the Remote.app.

I've opened ports, I followed all the advices from Apple support help and I test the connection via telnet but nothing has been useful for me.

I think the problem is related to Bonjour but I need an experienced opinion that can help me.

Why can't my devices on WiFi see my devices connected via ethernet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is usually down to the router involved, and a security setting disallowing traffic from machines connected to the Wifi interface to the (technically) more secure LAN interface.

If you provide more information on your router manufacture, model we may be able to assist more.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and sorry for the delay in my answer, but some subjects have kept me very busy lately. What you suggest is interesting. I tried every option in the firewall router but no results. The router is the ONT-Router ZNID-GPON-2426-EU: S2.5.031 (optic fiber). When I used an old ADSL router (before changing ISP) worked fine.